# AVIF editor recommendation

Tags: image-processing

Any recommendations for an image editor that can save in avif format? I am interested in outputting avif format files directly, without having to go through a secondary conversion process.

Comment: Interestingly enough the very latest Gimp can do this but it must be compiled against libheif...

Answer (score 1):

[GNU Image Manipulation Program](https://snapcraft.io/gimp) can do this. I'm using 2.10.22 here, and the option to save as a HEIF/AVIF is available.

[image: Save dialog from GIMP]

Comment: Yes, I see that now. The version of GIMP on the Ubuntu repository for 20.4 is an earlier one that does not yet have this feature.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I mentioned the snap as it's more up to date.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20.04, and I'm using the snap version 2.10.24. When trying to save as `.avif`, GIMP says, "The given filename does not have any known file extension." Ditto `.heif`. Is there something that I need to do to ensure compatibility?